# Clozure CL : an error occurs when requiring Cocoa framework

Tags: macos, cocoa, common-lisp, ccl

I'm trying to require Cocoa Framework on Mac OS X 10.11.4, but I cannot require it.

Log:

```
$ ccl --version
Version 1.11-r16635  (DarwinX8632)

$ ccl
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11-r16635  (DarwinX8632)!

? (require :COCOA)

:COCOA
("IDE-BUNDLE" "OBJC-PACKAGE" "SEQUENCE-UTILS" "NAME-TRANSLATION" "OBJC-CLOS" "OBJC-RUNTIME" "BRIDGE" "OBJC-SUPPORT" "COMPILE-HEMLOCK" "HEMLOCK" "COCOA")
? Unhandled exception 10 at 0x992bb43c, context->regs at #xbfffdbcc
Exception occurred while executing foreign code
 at _class_initialize + 9
received signal 10; faulting address: 0xbf7ffffc
? for help
[6330] Clozure CL kernel debugger: ^CKilled: 9
```

How to solve this?

Comment: Best to ask such a question on the CCL mailing list. See: https://lists.clozure.com/mailman/listinfo/openmcl-devel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the 64-bit version

```
$ ccl64 --version
Version 1.11-r16635  (DarwinX8664)

$ ccl64
Welcome to Clozure Common Lisp Version 1.11-r16635  (DarwinX8664)!

CCL is developed and maintained by Clozure Associates. For more information
about CCL visit http://ccl.clozure.com.  To enquire about Clozure's Common Lisp
consulting services e-mail info@clozure.com or visit http://www.clozure.com.

? (require :COCOA)
...
:COCOA
("IDE-BUNDLE" "OBJC-PACKAGE" "SEQUENCE-UTILS" "NAME-TRANSLATION" "OBJC-CLOS" "OBJC-RUNTIME" "BRIDGE" "OBJC-SUPPORT" "COMPILE-HEMLOCK" "HEMLOCK" "COCOA")
?
```